# Android - using ViewModels in RecyclerView does not update View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use a `RecyclerView` to show a list of timers, which has two buttons (start-stop) and an `EditText` (to show the time). Each `RecyclerItem` has a `ViewModel` with some `LiveData` (e.g. currentTime, status of the timer, ...). The timer works until a new timer is added to the `RecyclerView`. The new timer is working properly, the old one does not change the View by clicking a button. What I do not understand is, that the `Observer` of the first-timer still works correctly (the timer can be stopped by clicking the button, but the view of the button does not change) and the EditText also can be updated.
Here is a snippet of my `Fragment`, ´RecyclerAdapter `and ´ViewModel` class. The `ViewModel` is stored in my `Squad` class.

### Fragment

```
 class SquadOverViewFragment: Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: SquadViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentSquadOverviewBinding
    private var adapter: RecyclerAdapterSquad? = null


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_ats_squad_overview, container, false)


        binding.atsMonitoringFABAdd.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(SquadOverViewFragmentDirections.actionOverviewToEnterCarrier())
        }

        container?.context.let {
            binding.atsMonitoringRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(it)
            adapter = viewModel.squadList.value?.let { it1 -> RecyclerAdapterSquad(it1) }
            binding.atsMonitoringRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
            binding.atsMonitoringRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))

        }

        viewModel.squadList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
          /* Here a new timer is added to the list */
            it?.let { squadList ->
                adapter?.let { adapter ->
                    adapter.squadList = squadList
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        })
        return binding.root
    }

}
```

### RecyclerAdapter:

```
class RecyclerAdapterSquad(var squadList: ArrayList<Squad>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterSquad.ViewHolder>() {


    private lateinit var context: Context

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        context = parent.context
        var viewHolder = ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_view_ats_squad, parent, false), context)
        return viewHolder
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = squadList[position]
        holder.bindView(item)
    }

    //outside the range -> remove observer
    override fun onViewRecycled(holder: ViewHolder) {
        if (holder.squad?.viewModel?.currTime?.hasObservers() == true) {
            holder.squad?.viewModel?.currTime?.removeObservers(holder.viewLifecycleOwner)
        }

        if (holder.squad?.viewModel?.changeTimerStatus?.hasObservers() == true) {
            holder.squad?.viewModel?.changeTimerStatus?.removeObservers(holder.viewLifecycleOwner)
        }

        super.onViewRecycled(holder)

    }

    override fun getItemCount() = squadList.size

    class ViewHolder(view: View, context: Context) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener, ViewModelStoreOwner, LifecycleOwner {

        val appViewModelStore: ViewModelStore by lazy { ViewModelStore() }

        var view: View = view
        var squad: Squad? = null
        private var context = context
        var viewLifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner

        init {
            view.setOnClickListener(this)
            viewLifecycleOwner = context as LifecycleOwner
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View) {}

        companion object {
            private val ItemId = "ITEM-ID"
        }

        fun bindView(squad: Squad) {
            this.squad = squad

            val playButton = view.imageButtonSquadPlayPause
            val stopButton = view.imageButtonSquadStop

            if (squad.viewModel == null) {
                squad.viewModel = SquadViewRecyclerViewModel()
                squad.viewModel?.initSquad(squad, context)
            }

            squad.viewModel?.currTime?.observe(context as LifecycleOwner, Observer { currTime ->
                view.editTextSquadTimer.setText(currTime.toString())

            })

            squad.viewModel?.changeTimerStatus?.observe(context as LifecycleOwner, Observer { changedStatus ->
                if(changedStatus){
                    when (squad.viewModel!!.status) {
                        TimerStatus.READY -> {
                            view.imageButtonSquadPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ats_recycler_view_squad_item_play_icon)
                            makeTimerChangeable()
                        }
                        TimerStatus.IN_ACTION -> {
                            view.imageButtonSquadPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ats_recycler_view_squad_item_pause_icon)
                            view.imageButtonSquadStop.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            makeTimerUnchangable()
                        }
                        TimerStatus.ON_PAUSE -> {
                            view.imageButtonSquadPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ats_recycler_view_squad_item_play_icon)
                            view.constraintViewRecyclerViewSquad.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
                            makeTimerChangeable()
                        }
                       TimerStatus.FINISHED -> {
                            view.buttonATSMonitoringConfirm.isClickable = false
                            view.imageButtonSquadStop.isClickable = false

                            playButton.visibility = View.GONE
                            stopButton.visibility = View.GONE

                            view.editTextSquadTimer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                            makeTimerUnchangable()

                        }
                        TimerStatus.TIME_OUT -> {
                            playButton.isClickable = false
                            stopButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            stopButton.isClickable = false

                            playButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                            stopButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                            view.editTextSquadTimer.setText(context.getString(R.string.ats_monitoring_timer_info_time_out))

                            makeTimerUnchangable()

                        }
                    }
                    squad.viewModel?.resetChangeStatusFlag()
                }


            })




            // start countdown with play button
            playButton.setOnClickListener {
                squad.viewModel?.playButtonClicked(view.editTextSquadTimer.text.toString(), context)
            }

            // stop countdown with stop button
            stopButton.setOnClickListener {
                squad.viewModel?.stopButtonClicked()
            }

        }


        private fun makeTimerUnchangable() {
            view.editTextSquadTimer.isClickable = false
            view.editTextSquadTimer.isFocusable = false
            view.editTextSquadTimer.isFocusableInTouchMode = false
            view.editTextSquadTimer.isCursorVisible = false
        }

        private fun makeTimerChangeable() {
            view.editTextSquadTimer.isClickable = true
            view.editTextSquadTimer.isFocusable = true
            view.editTextSquadTimer.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
            view.editTextSquadTimer.isCursorVisible = true
        }

        override fun getViewModelStore(): ViewModelStore {
            return appViewModelStore
        }

        override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle {
            return this.context as Lifecycle
        }


    }

}
```

### ViewModel

```
class SquadViewRecyclerViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private lateinit var timer: CountDownTimer

    var status = TimerStatus.READY
    private lateinit var context: Context

    private val _currTime = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val currTime: LiveData<String>
        get() = _currTime

    private val _changeTimerStatus = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val changeTimerStatus: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _changeTimerStatus

    init {
        _changeTimerStatus.value = false
    }

    fun initSquad(squad: Squad, context: Context) {
        _currTime.value = "1:01"
        this.context = context
    }

    private fun initTimer(time: Long) {
        timer = object : CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                _currTime.value = generateTimeString(millisUntilFinished)
            }
            override fun onFinish() {
                status = TimerStatus.TIME_OUT
                _changeTimerStatus.value = true
            }

        }

    }

    private fun startTimer(time: String) {
        if (this::timer.isInitialized) {
            timer.cancel()
        }
        initTimer(generateMillSecFromString(time))
        timer.start()

    }

    private fun stopTimer() {
        if (this::timer.isInitialized) {
            timer.cancel()
        }
    }

    private fun pauseTimer() {
        stopTimer()
    }

    private fun resumeTimer(time: String) {
        startTimer(time)
    }

    fun playButtonClicked(time: String?, context: Context) {
        when (status) {
            TimerStatus.READY -> {
                time?.let { startTimer(time) }
                status = TimerStatus.IN_ACTION
                _changeTimerStatus.value = true
            }
            TimerStatus.IN_ACTION -> {
                pauseTimer()
                status = TimerStatus.ON_PAUSE
                _changeTimerStatus.value = true

            }
            TimerStatus.ON_PAUSE -> {
                time?.let { resumeTimer(time) }
                status = TimerStatus.IN_ACTION
                _changeTimerStatus.value = true
            }
            TimerStatus.TIME_OUT -> {
                status = TimerStatus.FINISHED
                _changeTimerStatus.value = true
            }
        }
    }


    fun stopButtonClicked() {
        stopTimer()
        status = TimerStatus.FINISHED
        _changeTimerStatus.value = true
    }

    fun resetChangeStatusFlag(){
        _changeTimerStatus.value = false
    }

    private fun generateTimeString(ms: Long): String {
        var sec = ms / 1000
        var min = sec / 60
        sec %= 60

        return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d:%02d", min, sec)
    }

    private fun generateMillSecFromString(timeString: String): Long {
        var timeInSec: Long

        if (timeString.contains(":")) {
            lateinit var min: String
            val indexMin = timeString.indexOf(":")
            if (indexMin == 0) {
                min = "0"
            } else {
                min = timeString.substring(0, indexMin)
            }
            val sec = timeString.substring(indexMin + 1)
            timeInSec = java.lang.Long.valueOf(min) * 60 * 1000 + java.lang.Long.valueOf(sec) * 1000

        } else {
            timeInSec = java.lang.Long.valueOf(timeString) * 1000 * 60
        }

        return timeInSec
    }

}
```

### fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/atsMonitoringFABAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/ats_monitoring_fab_orange"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:maxImageSize="32dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ats_monitoring_fab_icon_add_squad" />


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/atsMonitoringRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/atsMonitoringFABAdd"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />




    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

### recycler_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutSquadContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="1dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="12dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/constraintViewRecyclerViewAtsSquad"
        android:background="@color/white">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonSquadPlayPause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextSquadTimer"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ats_recycler_view_squad_item_play_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonSquadStop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextSquadTimer"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageButtonSquadPlayPause"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ats_recycler_view_squad_id_stop_icon" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextSquadTimer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="datetime"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:theme="@style/ATSMonitoring"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageButtonSquadStop" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Your question looks interesting, but with only the code snippet from the ViewHolder, it's hard to tell why your app does not behave like it should, If you provide us with a [MCVE], I'd like to set up a small sample app and do some debugging.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I could not find a solution. I think the problem is, that the link between `RecyclerItem` and `ViewModel` will still exist even the observer is removed. 
My current solution to this problem is not the best way, because the `RecyclerView` cannot do what it was made for: I set the flag `isRecyclable` to false in the viewHolder. Now the `ViewModel` is always connected to the same `RecyclerItem` in the `RecyclerList`.