# RecyclerView - memory increasing when swiping

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, out-of-memory

I have a problem with the RecyclerView. I need to set the recycler flag `viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false)` to false for some important reasons (ViewModel, LiveData,..). When I add a lot of items to the list, the app works fine, the memory does not raise dramatically, but when i swipe up and down the memory increase dramatically. My Questions: Why does memory consumption increase when swiping? The views are already added, so why ist the memory increasing?

Comment: Where is the code? How can we tell you something without see any row of code?

Answer (score 3):

From [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#setisrecyclable)

```
fun setIsRecyclable(recyclable: Boolean): Unit
```

> Informs the recycler whether this item can be recycled. Views which
> are not recyclable will not be reused for other items until
> setIsRecyclable() is later set to true. Calls to setIsRecyclable()
> should always be paired (one call to setIsRecyclabe(false) should
> always be matched with a later call to setIsRecyclable(true)). Pairs
> of calls may be nested, as the state is internally reference-counted.

The recycler view basically destroys the views and recreates them when it is necessary (within the user-screen-visible range). Since you set `viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false)` the views won't be recycled leads to increase in the memory.

> Q: The views are already added, so why is the memory increasing?

The views already added are not destroyed and again new views are created when you swipe up which leads to increase in the memory.

`viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false)` is not the solution for your expected result.

Comment: I can't recycle the view of the item, because I use a `ViewModel` with `LiveData` in every item and I can't find a solution to keep the `ViewModel` connecting with the correct `RecyclerItem`. 
I would like to recycle the views if I know how to solve this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212570/android-using-viewmodels-in-recyclerview-does-not-update-view).